# How do update IV of a ctx of type EVP_CIPHER_CTX (open ssl 1.1.0)

Tags: openssl

I am in the process of upgrading my Openssl package to 1.1.0 series.
However as Openssl has made many structures opaque I am unable to update the iv of a particular ctx.

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx; // This was EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx; for version 1.0.x series

EVP_DecryptInit(ctx, cipher, keydata, iv);
```

for a particular scenario i need to update the iv.
in the earlier version of openssl 1.0.x series, I did it with

```
memcpy(nextIv, &ctx.iv, DES3_BLOCK_SIZE);
```

however after changing it to

```
memcpy(nextIv, ctx->iv, DES3_BLOCK_SIZE);
```

I get a compiler error

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX' {aka 'struct evp_cipher_ctx_st'}
>   memcpy(nextIv, ctx->iv, DES3_BLOCK_SIZE);

I assume this is because the structure has been made opaque.

What can I replace the `memcpy` statement with for updating the iv of the ctx to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I went through the Openssl code and figured out that

EVP_DecryptInit_ex()

Internally does a memcpy() of the iv for the ctx. So doing the below worked for me.

EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, cipher, NULL, key, newIv);

Answer (score 0):

After OpenSSL 1.1.0 you can access ctx->iv like this.

```
const unsigned char *EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv(const EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx);
unsigned char *EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_noconst(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx);
```